# Java, Passing parameters from one class to other class

Tags: java, class, parameters

I want to keep all validation methods (phone number validation, numeric validation) in a separate class and let the other classes to access validation methods commonly.How do I do this? Can someone assist me please.

```
class Validation {

  public static boolean validateQty(String txt) {

        String regx = "^0([1-9]){2}([0-9]){7}$";
        Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(regx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(txt);
        return matcher.find();
  }

  public static boolean validateLetters(String txt) {

        String regx = "[a-zA-Z]+\\.?";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(txt);
        return matcher.find();
  }
```

}

```
class ItemDetails {

  private void addItem() {
        boolean b = validateLetters(txtItemName.getText()); // I want to pass txtItemName value to Class Validation's validateLetters()
        boolean c = validateQty(txtQty.getText());
  }
```

}

Comment: Validation.validateLetters(txtItemName.getText()); ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are static methods you can access like this

```
boolean b = Validation .validateLetters(txtItemName.getText()); 
        boolean c = Validation .validateQty(txtQty.getText());
```

or create an object of Validation

```
Validation v=new Validation ();

boolean b = v .validateLetters(txtItemName.getText()); 
        boolean c =v .validateQty(txtQty.getText());
```

Answer (score 2):

Since these are static methods, you can call them by prefixing the class name:

```
    boolean b = Validation.validateLetters(txtItemName.getText()); 
    boolean c = Validation.validateQty(txtQty.getText());
```

You might also find it useful to pass the entire item to a single validate() method.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get that. Could you explain little more how to pass entire item to a single validate() method. Please

Comment: You could define a new class Item to hold all the properties of an item. Define a method Validation.validate( Item item ) that performs all necessary validation for an item.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean b = Validation .validateLetters(txtItemName.getText()); 
boolean c = Validation .validateQty(txtQty.getText());
```

Since your method in Validation class method validateLetters and validateQty is   static you can call it this way . Otherwise you have to create instance of Validation first. Like

```
Validation v = new Validation();
boolean b = v.validateLetters(txtItemName.getText());
boolean c = v.validateQty(txtQty.getText());
```